# VSTO Ribbon Add-in Accessing Resource Files

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, clickonce, ribbon

I am creating a Ribbon Add-in using VB.net and Click-once deployment. I have a xml file that is included in the package (set to Content and Copy Always) that I am trying to load in order to build a dynamicMenu item on the ribbon. Works fine when run on my machine during development; however, when the ribbon is installed on another machine, it cannot find the xml file to load and the menu is blank. I've tried a number of different methods based on things I've found on stack exchange and around the web but I have been unsuccessful so far.

I'm sure it is pretty straight forward and it is the last thing holding up the deployment in the office.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the XML file get deployed into the correct folder (like did you verify through Windows exporer)?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure what the right folder would be. I was under the impression that when you specify the file as being "Content" in the build action - the build process automatically associates the file with vsto add-in, allowing me to simply load the file with XDocument.Load("Filename.xml"). When I build the ribbon in visual studio and use the Load call above, it works fine, but when it is deployed, it doesn't work.

Comment: In my experience, you need to specify the path. I've used constructs such as `System.IO.Path.Combine(Globals.ThisAddIn.filePath, "TrailPatterns.potx")` successfully.

Comment: I've not tried Globals.ThisAddIn.filePath yet. But I did stumble upon a construct that appears to work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses - I seemed to have stumbled upon an answer.

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

Appears to provide the path to any data files marked "Content". It works when deployed to other machines.

I could not find any known issues with using this path, anyone know if any that I should know about?

Answer (score 0):

Existing answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```cs
  //Get the assembly information
  System.Reflection.Assembly assemblyInfo = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

  //Location is where the assembly is run from 
  string assemblyLocation = assemblyInfo.Location;

  //CodeBase is the location of the ClickOnce deployment files
  Uri uriCodeBase = new Uri(assemblyInfo.CodeBase);
  string ClickOnceLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(uriCodeBase.LocalPath.ToString());
```